# Undefined is not an object in React Native project

Tags: android, react-native

I'm trying to open existing React Native project in the emulator on Windows 10, but it throws this error:

```
undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNativeParse2.default.Object.extend')
```

I'm using 0.45.1 version of React Native. Backend is Parse Server. Why is this happening?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Found this on [Github issues](https://github.com/shoutem/ui/issues/241). Try this for now:

```
edit package.json -> Replace 0.45.1 with 0.43.4 for react-native

'rm -rf node_modules' //get rid of previous module installations based on 0.45.1
npm install
react-native link
react-native run-android // but in separate window be running 'npm start' first.
```

Comment: It didn't work. Can't run npm install. I'm trying to open an existing project. When I create a new project, node_modules get installed automatically. But I'm working on existig project.